# Android: How to allow user to set custom wallpaper in an activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making a simple chat application which I want users to be able to set their own chat room background.

Which directory should I store the images and in what format ?
Will user be able to access and delete the file from some file browser app ?

The requirements are:

1. The selected image should be stored in the device (not uploaded to the database)
2. If new user logs in, and logs out. Then, the old user logs in again, the wallpapers should remain there.
3. Different chat room can have different wallpapers.

(Basically, the wallpaper feature is only apply to that device.)

Comment: Just wondering where is the code that you have tried?

Comment: It's possible to create `users/userID/wallpaper/chatRoomID.png` directory in the app externalDirextory. I haven't tried this because I'm not sure whether it is a correct approach. I think that there is a better approach.